# Tensorflow - FutureWarning

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here's the Issue I get when i type `import tensorflow`

```
c:\users\otter\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
c:\users\otter\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
c:\users\otter\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
c:\users\otter\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
c:\users\otter\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
c:\users\otter\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
```

My Installation Process:

1st: `pip install tensorflow==1.13.1 --ignore-installed`

2nd: `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15`

My Cuda Version is `10.0` and cudnn is `v7.6.5`

Why's numpy throwing me all these errors?

I have to use Tensorflow 1.31.1 with GPU because of the project i'm doing it doesn't support Tensorflow 2.x :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I SOLVED IT!**

Do `pip uninstall numpy`

Then do `pip install numpy==1.16.4`

The older version of Tensorflow doesn't support newer version of Numpy.